# The requested clipboard operation failed

Tags: vb.net, clipboard

I've using vb.net 2003 and some of the times this error arises. Can anyone know on how this error arises and how to fix it?

Error: The requested clipboard operation failed

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: This would be a better question if there were more detail....

Comment: What clipboard operation are you trying to do?  Are you copying, pasting, clearing, monitoring, etc.?  User-initiated or automated? Help me help you.  Improve your question and I'll upvote it, AND try to help you out.

Comment: Try solution that I posted on this page https://stackoverflow.com/a/52438404/5639198

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I googled this question to see what I'd see, and a lot of people have asked this question, and none of them have gotten a solid answer...

So I went to the MSDN documentation and found a note that explains what most people who have asked this question describe... The symptom usually appears when the user switches to another application while the code is running.  The note is quoted below, with the link to the documentation following:

> All Windows-based applications share
> the system Clipboard, so the contents
> are subject to change when you switch
> to another application.
>
> An object must be serializable for it
> to be put on the Clipboard. If you
> pass a non-serializable object to a
> Clipboard method, the method will fail
> without throwing an exception. See
> System.Runtime.Serialization for more
> information on serialization. If your
> target application requires a very
> specific data format, the headers
> added to the data in the serialization
> process may prevent the application
> from recognizing your data. To
> preserve your data format, add your
> data as a Byte array to a MemoryStream
> and pass the MemoryStream to the
> SetData method.
>
> The Clipboard class can only be used
> in threads set to single thread
> apartment (STA) mode. To use this
> class, ensure that your Main method is
> marked with the STAThreadAttribute
> attribute.
>
> Special considerations may be
> necessary when using the metafile
> format with the Clipboard. Due to a
> limitation in the current
> implementation of the DataObject
> class, the metafile format used by the
> .NET Framework may not be recognized
> by applications that use an older
> metafile format. In this case, you
> must interoperate with the Win32
> Clipboard application programming
> interfaces (APIs). For more
> information, see article 323530,
> "Metafiles on Clipboard Are Not
> Visible to All Applications," in the
> Microsoft Knowledge Base at
> http://support.microsoft.com.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx

Funnily enough, this makes sense of a strange behavior I noticed in one of my own apps.  I have an app that writes to an Excel spreadsheet (actually, to hundreds of them, modifying hundreds of cells each).  I don't use the clipboard at all, just the Interop API for excel, yet when it's running, my clipboard clears every time a new spreadsheet is created.  In my case, Excel is messing with the clipboard, even there is no discernible reason for it to do so.  I'd chalk it up to one of those mysterious Windows phenomena that we mortals will never understand.

At any rate, thanks to your question, I think I understand my issue, so +1 to you for helping me out.

Answer (score 4):

I have that error while trying to:

```
Clipboard.Clear();
...
Clipboard.SetText(...);
```

For solving it I replace `Clipboard.Clear()` with pinvoking some methods from the `user32.dll`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetOpenClipboardWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool OpenClipboard(IntPtr hWndNewOwner);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool EmptyClipboard();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool CloseClipboard();

...

IntPtr handleWnd = GetOpenClipboardWindow();
OpenClipboard(handleWnd);
EmptyClipboard();
CloseClipboard();

...

Clipboard.SetText(...);
```

I use C# here, but vb version could be easily created from it.

Comment: Thanks man! This did the trick to me. I was using `Clipboard.GetText`, and getting the same error. I called your lines to clear the clipboard, then issued a Ctrl+C with `SendKeys.Send()`, and could call `Clipboard.GetText` without any error. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it was intermittent with my code failing 60% of the time. Using visual studio I found the issue to be a clipboard read.  After reading David's detailed post I had enough additional information to troubleshoot my problem.   I had made two recent changes to my computer enviroment.  I had started using both DropBox and Chrome Remote Desktop.

Chrome Desktop shares the clipboard between computers so I suppected it was the cause.  The problem did not go away when I quit using remote desktop so I disabled Dropbox and the problem was gone and does not exist with remoted desktop active.  I don't understand or like the idea that dropbox is aggressivly accessing the clipboard, so I am no longer using it.  I could have added error handling to my code at the point of failure and continued using Dropbox but I will not use a program that is accessing my clipboard with out my knowledge.  Big security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance that UltraVNC is running. I have issues when that application is running in the background on the client PC side. When I close VNC, I can copy to the clipboard successfully. This is not really a satisfying solution but at least I know in my case the source of the problem.