# Requested Clipboard operation did not succeed

Tags: winforms, clipboard

```
Exception Type: ExternalException

Message: Requested Clipboard operation did not succeed.

Method: ThrowIfFailed

Source: System.Windows.Forms



Stack Trace:

   at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.ThrowIfFailed(Int32 hr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(Object data, Boolean copy, Int32 retryTimes, Int32 retryDelay)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(String text, TextDataFormat format)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(String text)
   at Deerfield.Base.Controls.DataGridView.ProcessCmdKey(Message& msg, Keys keyData) in C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\deerfield\src\core\Deerfield\Deerfield.Base\Controls\DataGridView.cs:line 555
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessCmdKey(Message& msg, Keys keyData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessCmdKey(Message& msg, Keys keyData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.ProcessCmdKey(Message& msg, Keys keyData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(Control target, Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
```

I googled this, but I cannot get a decent answer as to why this is happening.

The MSDN documentation says that this often happens when the user switches to another application, but it does not appear that this was the case.

Comment: Somebody else probably had the clipboard open. My guess is that somebody opened it and forgot to close it. Since you didn't show any code, I can only guess.

Comment: Something was being pasted into a dataGridCell. I have no code that does anything with it, it was the control itself

Comment: What language is that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Having a similar problem. Found this [entry](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/a23c31df-e645-4500-ab4a-e6178510a9b1),
which basically says to set `retryTimes` to 2 in the call:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(object data, bool copy, int retryTimes, int retryDelay)
```

Going to try it. Would be nice if anyone could post a reproducible test case.

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to use setDataObject. Is there any way to have the retry/retryDelay option while using setText?

Comment: @KristenApril: If you look at how the SetText method is implemented (using Reflector or something like that) it just wraps the call to SetDataObject. It first wraps the text in a DataObject class and then passes that into SetDataObject althoug calling SetDataObject will do this for you automatically so you really just want to use the same options that it uses internally for the call to SetText which is: 'SetDataObject(data, true, 10, 100);'

Comment: @BrutalDev: but if `SetText` internally uses `SetDataObject(data, true, 10, 100)`, then why calling straight `SetDataObject(data, true, 10, 100)` would change anything?

Comment: @user276648 I never said it would change anything. I was pointing out that the underlying call is the same (with a `retryTimes` set to 10) so if calling `SetDataObject` directly is in fact a solution, then you may as well call it with the same parameters.

Comment: In my case I was trying to copy a few MBs of data from a grid and then dump it to a file stream. Adding a five second wait fixed the problem. Turns out previously the data was being copied to Clipboard while I tried to access it for dumping part.

Answer (score 8):

The root cause is likely to be that you are doing two operations, typically a copy and a paste, and assume that the clipboard will be available. What happens is, that you do a copy (to update the clipboard) and then other clipboard viewers are reacting to it when you try to paste.  The defense is to have an except/sleep/retry mechanism around the paste operation, so that you can handle it gracefully.  Telling the user to shut down rpdclip and such, won't fly in a production application.
Also make sure that you're not (ab)using the clipboard as a crutch.  The clipboard is provided for the convenience of the USER, not the PROGRAMMER.

Comment: Agree, but when doing VBA / Office programming, there aren't many good ways to get data back and forth, and the systems were really designed with the clipboard as the main transport tool.

Answer (score 7):

EASY! I had the same issue and fixed it.

Just open Task Manager, search for `rdpclip.exe` under `Processes`, kill it. Then, open a new task and run it again.

Comment: This solves crash of Git Extensions. Thanks.  See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a23c31df-e645-4500-ab4a-e6178510a9b1/clipboard-error?forum=Vsexpressvb for more info.

Comment: For the Git Extensions crash, see [this issue](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/4542) which will be fixed in the upcoming 3.0 release. (There's an RC out now so please give it a shot if you can.)

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with an app but only when running it on an HP mini.

If I have C# express running so I can check the exception,

shutting down Google Chrome removes the problem.

reopening Google Chrome causes it to reappear.

But on my main 64 bit machine, no problem; and on my previous 32 bit machine, no problem either. Side effect of limited RAM perhaps?

Gerald

Answer (score 3):

It's some other application is using Clipboard now. Find out the application monitoring Clipboard and kill the process. Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using some VNC program (RealVNC) and your application use Clipboard from System.Windows.Forms.dll on main thread "The requested clipboard operation failed" will occur. This is my solution written in C# for .NET 3.5:

```
using System.Threading;

   var dataObject = new DataObject();
   private Clipboard()
   {
        //dataObject logic here

        Thread clipboardThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetClipboard));
        clipboardThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        clipboardThread.Start();
   }

   private void GetClipboard()
   {
         Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, true, 10, 100);
   }
```

Comment: I have this issue when running TightVNC viewer. Closing it makes the problem go away.
The weird thing is, all other software has no problem using the clipboard while vnc runs.
This approach made no difference for my C# console application..

Answer (score 1):

I used System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc method and PostMessage.

```
string clipboardText;

{
    clipboardText = "TEXT FOR CLIPBOARD";
    PostMessage(Handle, CLIPBOARD_BACKUP_MSG, 0, 0);
}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
{
    if (m.Msg == CLIPBOARD_BACKUP_MSG)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(clipboardText);
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: A couple of years later but the only thing that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, and use this code as [WireGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5795061/3996266) answered. but this code code makes an exception in my PC "Requested Clipboard operation did not succeed". I put this line a Try Catch statement

```
            try
            {
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(textBoxCodePan.Text, true, 10, 100);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
```

and did work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try running GetDataObject in while loop with Try catch. Eventually it will succeed.

```
    while (tempObj == null)
    {// get from the clipboard
        try
        {
            tempObj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: This approach may be dangerous. If the `GetDataObject()` call never succeeds then you can enter an infinite loop. Using a `retryCount` variable is safer.

Answer (score 1):

i had this problem and this worked for me , add this before setting text to clipboard (Clipboard.SetText(string Text))

so it finally become

```
Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetText(string Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

For myself, I found that the clipboard was still processing my request while I 
was putting a new one. 

`SendKeys.SendWait("^c");
Clipboard.GetText();`

So I added Sleep and it now works great.

`SendKeys.SendWait("^c");
Thread.Sleep(250);
Clipboard.GetText();`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason i got "Requested Clipboard operation did not succeed" exceptions every time when running

```
Dim s = "test"
Clipboard.SetDataObject(s, True, 10, 200)
```

But

```
Dim s = "test"
Clipboard.ContainsText()
Clipboard.SetDataObject(s, True, 10, 200)
```

worked every time.

However, interestingly

```
Try
    Dim s = "test"
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(s, True, 10, 200)
catch ex as exception
    Dim s = "test"
    Clipboard.ContainsText()
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(s, True, 10, 200)
end try
```

will fail on both SetDataObject calls

I'm sure its as transient error as i was setting clipboard content the other day without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly had this error when copying data from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, since then I couldn't copy anything.
Restarting explorer.exe process solved the issue. I guess the explorer process handles most of the clipboard action.