# Getting clipboard error from few applications when chrome is running - Datagridview on WinForm

Tags: c#, google-chrome, datagridview, clipboard, copy-paste

I am getting an error when I am trying to use ctrl + C and ctrl +V on a datagridview control.
This is not reproducible on my other machine.

**Further analyzing the case, I figured out that this issue occurs only if Google Chrome is running. If I close Google Chrome, it works fine as expected.**

This is the exception thrown by application,
Requested Clipboard operation did not succeed.

```
--STACK TRACE--

   at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.ThrowIfFailed(Int32 hr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(Object data, Boolean copy, Int32 retryTimes, Int32 retryDelay)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ProcessInsertKey(Keys keyData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

System.Windows.Forms
```

**This issue occurs with Internet Explorer as well.**

Is there anything that I have to do on datagridview.
Please help me out to troubleshoot this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Vijay

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to this question ..
[Requested Clipboard operation did not succeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707990/requested-clipboard-operation-did-not-succeed)

Also related ..

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/31da5cec-7d47-41f0-a2e5-ee16e609a871

From above link..

> The problem with the clipboard is that it is shared among all
>   processes and only one process can access it at a time. So if another
>   process uses the clipboard at the same time as your application then
>   you may get this exception. Your other computer may have a process
>   that uses the clipboard even when the process's window is not active
>   (e.g. the user is performing an action in your application). This is
>   also known to be a problem with Virtual machines.
>
> My advice is to catch the exception and try again a few times, sooner
>   or later the clipboard will be freed so you could use it. You could
>   inherit from the Clipboard class and provide additional methods that
>   you use in your application.

And one more..
http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/Requested-Clipboard-operation-did-not-succeed

Comment: Looks like the same issue , but unfortunately I do not have control over the ProcessCmdKey event. It is written in another assembly which I cannot access.